# Разработка на java под ios (IPhone)?

Tags: java, ios, iphone, mobile

Уважаемые программисты! Очень много противоречивой информации встречаю в интернете. Предположим мне вздумалось написать именно на java программу и именно под ios.

1. Можно ли разработать приложение на java под ios в принципе?

   - Есть многочисленные мнения, что под iOS можно разрабатывать только используя Mac в комплекте с Objective-C и iOs SDK (iOs SDK не поддерживает java!). Однако есть и официальная документация Oracle, которая говорит, что java [может](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/oracle_brings_java_to_ios) быть использована как средство разработки под ios.
2. Можно ли залить java приложения написаннного под ios в АpStore?
3. Можно ли с помощью java приложения под ios получить доступ к перефирийным устройствам IPhon'a, таким как камера и micro usb?
4. В какой интегрированной среде разработки и с какими модулями можно поразрабатывать Java приложения под ios?

   - Как бы подразумевается, что Мас'a у автора нет, и устранять это желания&возможности тоже нет.
5. Есть ли какая-нибудь профессиональная литература по этому вопросу? (желательно русскоязычная)

**PS**. Если вы знаете ответ хотя бы на одну пятую часть вопроса, пожалуйста отвечайте! Очень нужна информация. Если вы знаете о подводных камнях сего дела, тоже напишите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вот, например, мультиплафторменный транслятор Java для IOS от Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/multi-os-engine-technology-preview-from-intel-first-hand-experience-in-creating-an-ios-app?utm_source=Develop+Blog+http://www.develop-online.net/&utm_medium=Text+Link&utm_campaign=Android_EMEA_Q1-16_Developer-Blog_Blog-Page?08032016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Да, можно через [RoboVM](http://robovm.com/) или [JavaFXPorts](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_overview)
2. Да, http://svanimpe.be/blog/pong-ios.html
3. Да, RoboVM создает мост между Java и Objective-C
4. Для RoboVM необходимы XCode и коммандные утилиты, единственный вариант, который приходит на ум это поставить виртуальную Mac OS X
5. Да, но очень мало, даже на английском языке. Лучшие ссылки указаны сверху.

В заключении, разработка java программ на iOS вполне реальна, но при этом имеется ввиду, что программа сама кросс-платформенная (win, mac, linux, android, ios, etc). Потому что писать 1 общий код в таких случаях выгодней с точки зрения времени работы. Если программа эксклюзивна на ios, то писать на java не имеет большого смысла и потраченное время на разработку не будет являться оправданным.

Comment: А по времени, на ваш авторитетный взгляд, небольшое приложение типа пасьянса по трудозатратам во сколько раз будет отличаться? (по сравнению с objective-C?)

Comment: Не думаю, что разница будет очень большой, но здесь уже все зависит от Вашего знания этих языков и технологий связанных с ними.