# Можно ли писать на Java для iOS?

Tags: java, ios, apple, jvm

До меня дошли страшные слухи, что на iOS нет JVM. Более того, до меня дошли страшные слухи, что будто бы фирма Эппл не разрешает ставить JVM на iOS.

Вопросы:

1. Так ли это? Действительно ли на iOS нет JVM?
2. Так ли это? Действительно ли Эппл не разрешает ставить JVM на iOS?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445849/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-ios-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под MacOS ставится стандартная Java >= 8, [информация здесь](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml)

Под iOS [криво и косо ставится OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/ios.html), через эмуляцию и все такое.

Answer (score 0):

Есть имплементации jvm под iOS. Это ответ как на первый, так и на второй вопрос

Comment: Какая? Где? Маловато информации для ответа...

Comment: https://github.com/digitalgust/miniJVM?